# WPF Arrange Panel Children

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DockPanel with some images nested inside.

```
<DockPanel x:Name="ControlStack"
           Background="LightGray"
           MouseLeftButtonUp="ECIControlStack_MouseLeftButtonUp">
   <DockPanel.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
           <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,3,0"/>
       </Style>
   </DockPanel.Resources>
   <Image x:Name="FirstImage" Source="{Binding GpsImage}" Height="36" Width="36"/>
   <Image x:Name="SecondImage" Source="{Binding YellowIcon}" Height="36"/>
   <Image x:Name="ThirdImage" Source="{Binding RedIcon}" Height="36"/>
   <Image x:Name="FourthImage" Source="{Binding GreenIcon}" Height="36"/>
</DockPanel>
```

I would like to change the order of the items programmatically from code behind or really anywhere.

Just doing some general tinkering, trying to even get the objects to move.

I've attempted something such as:

```
Rect rectangleBounds = new Rect();
rectangleBounds = ControlStack.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(
                      new Rect(0, 0, ControlStack.Width, ControlStack.Height));

Canvas.SetLeft(FirstImage, rectangleBounds.Left + 100);
Canvas.SetRight(FirstImage, rectangleBounds.Right + 100);
Canvas.SetTop(FirstImage, rectangleBounds.Top + 100);
Canvas.SetBottom(FirstImage, rectangleBounds.Bottom + 100);
```

But to no avail.

1.I don't think this works because it is in the dockpanel and not a canvas child?

2.Even if it did work it would move freely and I assume destroy the dockPanel stack order.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Yes you are right, you can't move things around in a dockpanel except by the dock panel enumerations or tricky offset logic.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx   To do what you want to do you need to change the panel to be a canvas.  You could do it in a grid too, but it's more difficult...

Comment: If you really only want to "change the order of the items", you could easily remove an element from the DockPanel's `Children` collection and insert it again at another index position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, changing the order is easiest by simply adjusting the index of the images. I ended up using the following:

```
   private void SetTopImage()
    {
        Image NewTopImage = FindIconPriority(); // Finds what Icon I would like to have in front.

        ControlStack.Children.Remove(NewTopImage);
        ControlStack.Children.Insert(0, NewTopImage);
    }
```